# Interactive Python Terminal Not Printing Correctly

Tags: python, terminal, output, exit

I'm having a bit of a weird bug with my interactive python and I was hoping for some help.

First of all, my python is running from `/opt/local/bin/python`, which is totally fine and great.

However, when I'm running python from the command line, a few weird things have been occurring. Here is an example of one:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 05:35:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2
>>> 2
```

Note, after typing 2, I am only hitting enter once. However, it is not printing out normally. I am not sure why it is like this. After hitting enter just that once, I can do something like:

```
print('this is also weird')
>>> this is also weird
```

And that is how the output is shown.

The worst however, is when I try to exit using `exit()` from the interactive terminal. This is an example of what happens.

```
>>> bshprmpt$ -bash: f: command not found
bshprmpt$ bshprmpt$ bshprmpt$ bshprmpt$ bshprmpt$
```

Note, that all I am doing is hitting enter after each line. I typed f just to see if anything else would happen. I want to exit interactive python and have it jump back to:

```
bshprmpt$ 
bshprmpt$ 
bshprmpt$ 
bshprmpt$ 
bshprmpt$ 
bshprmpt$
```

If I hit enter a bunch of times. Can anyone help? This is a relatively weird bug and I've looked around a bunch but haven't been able to find a lot of supporting information.

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:** I should have spent more time searching around. Thanks again for the solution. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/965133/python2-7-from-macports-stdin-issue/975608#975608) is another link on superuser. The solution actually came from one of my professors at school. No surprise there.

Comment: Does it happen also when you run the above examples in a fresh terminal window?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again? Joking (sort of), but you could try running the reset command. There is also this known issue with macports.  http://superuser.com/questions/983755/os-x-terminal-behaves-oddly-after-running-python-interactively

Comment: This can happen when a program that used e.g. `curses` or other direct terminal manipulation calls was terminated without cleaning up whatever non-standard modes were set on the terminal. Usually `stty sane` will clear up most of that...

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes unfortunately it does also happen in a fresh terminal. I have tried to reset it. I should have said that sorry about it.

Comment: @twalberg Interesting to know. Yes `stty sane` works as a temporary fix, but not indefinitely.

Comment: @rtk22 Brilliant! Thanks for the catch. I didn't realize that this problem was so heavily documented. Do you want to like make an official answer so that way I can approve / upvote your response? Thanks again :)

The line of code that pretty much did the trick was one I found off that [link](http://superuser.com/questions/983755/os-x-terminal-behaves-oddly-after-running-python-interactively). I ran:

`sudo port selfupdate && sudo port clean python27 && sudo port install python27 +readline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with MacPorts documented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/983755/os-x-terminal-behaves-oddly-after-running-python-interactively) and [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48807).

It appears the fix is to install python with the "+readline" option.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port clean python27
sudo port install python27 +readline
```